# How to select rows that matches "multiple rows condition" in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

So I created a sql fiddle to explain my problem much clearer:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f35416

As you can see I have 3 tables and 1 of them links the 2 others.

```
table name: tags
---------------------
id | tag      | value
---------------------
1  | color    | green
2  | color    | yellow
3  | color    | red
4  | category | dress
5  | category | car

table name: product_tags_link
---------------------
product_id | tag_id
---------------------
1          | 1
1          | 5
2          | 1
3          | 2
3          | 5
4          | 4
5          | 4
5          | 1

table name: products
---------------------
id  | name
---------------------
1   | green car
2   | yellow only
3   | yellow car
4   | dress only
5   | green dress
```

How can I make it so If I can get whatever product that have a "color" "green" and "category" "car"?

I tried doing:

```
select `ptl`.`product_id` 
from `product_tags_link` as `ptl`
    inner join `tags` on `tags`.`id` = `ptl`.`tag_id`
where ((`tags`.`tag` = "green") or (`tags`.`value` = "car"))
```

but it will return other product that is green OR car. changing it to `and` will not return anything as well.

I'm hoping to receive is `product_id: 1` which have both `color:green` and `category:car`

Comment: Can you update with the desired result as you would like it to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join all 3 tables, group by product and set the condition in the HAVING clause:

```
select p.id, p.name 
from products p
inner join product_tags_link l on l.product_id = p.id
inner join tags t on t.id = l.tag_id
where (t.tag = 'category' and t.value = 'car')
   or (t.tag = 'color' and t.value = 'green')
group by p.id, p.name
having count(distinct t.tag) = 2
```

Or:

```
select p.id, p.name 
from products p
inner join product_tags_link l on l.product_id = p.id
inner join tags t on t.id = l.tag_id
where (t.tag, t.value) in (('category', 'car'), ('color', 'green'))
group by p.id, p.name
having count(distinct t.tag) = 2
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=eeaf3bb7769f577801f8692d2ac73c0c).
Results:

```
> id | name
> -: | :---
>  1 | test
```

Answer (score -1):

I would omit the joining table and do a simple join as follows:

```
SELECT 
    p.id AS product_id
FROM
    products p
        LEFT JOIN
    tags t ON p.id = t.id
WHERE
    t.value = 'green'
        AND p.name LIKE '%car%'
```

Comment: Sorry, but this will notn do the job.

Comment: By including the wildcard as in '%car%' (see the solution above) it returns a result for me. Try it out.